# How to sing higher head voice notes more quietly?

Tags: voice, vocal-cords

Is it possible to sing the higher notes we access by using the head voice?

Why are higher notes so much louder when sang, and attempting to sing them very quiet often results in voice cracking? As loosen as I try to be, I still can't achieve a very low volume.

Why can we sing by using falsetto and chest voice at any volume we desire?

Is it possible to sing any note within a vocal range with the same volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your last question is probably yes. But I'm guessing that this is not exactly what you want to know. It's also about timbre not just volume. If you keep a consistent medium or low volume you might still be able to bridge smoothly but your voice will probably start thining out as your get to the 4th octave. That might or might not be what you want. Some people refer to this as early bridging because the point that your voice shifts to head voice happens at a lower note.

As to why your voice is cracking is simply because it's one of the hardest things to do. It requires tons of practice. It's one thing to hit high notes but doing it in every dynamic level is very advanced. This is not for beginners but you might want to practice with the messa di voce exercise. It's basically a volume swell on a certain note. Start with a small, almost falsetto note and then let it get bigger and louder over a few seconds. Then you can also go backwards and gradually shrink the note. Practice with higher notes when you're comfortable.